# lcd doesn't show any characters , is the problem in the lcd itself?

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd

That's my wiring besides another part of a project ( ultrasonic sensor) which works correctly on the same breadboard, Rs 12 , En 11 , d4 8 , d5 9 , d6 10 , d7 13 I tried to change power of arduino from 5 to 3.3 volt & I tried to use a power adapter

the lcd sometimes show me dark boxes for seconds when I use the potentiometer often in the first row of the display 
i used the simulation of tinker cad & it's working but doesn't work on my project & i used the default arduino code with changing the pins number

[image]

code :

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

const int rs = 12, en = 11, d4 = 8, d5 = 9, d6 = 10, d7 = 13;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

void setup() {
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.print("hello, world!");
}

void loop() {
  // Turn off the display:
  lcd.noDisplay();
  delay(50000);
  // Turn on the display:
  lcd.display();
  delay(50000);
}
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: Your code will print on the LCD and immediately turn it off, then wait for 50 seconds and turn it on again. Have you waited the 50s to check if something is shown?

Comment: yes I waited for it I doesn't show me any character

Comment: In addition to the 6 signals you described, I see 6 more. Allowing that the LCD needs power & ground, and one is the potentiometer, what are the other 3? Do you have a part number for the display, or can you show a definition of its inputs? What is the 10K pullup resistor for?

Comment: Vss gnd , VDD 5v , V0 to the middle terminal of potentiometer used for adjusting contrast , RW gnd  , 10 k resistor connected to anode I used it beacuse of the schematic in this link  https://www.hackster.io/MylesBartlett/ultrasonic-security-system-with-object-distance-display-0d7140?f=1#    I tried to remove it but It made the lcd stop working or having power

Comment: If you are using 4-bit structure you must use LSB not the MSB. Try your code by connecting your wires to d0,d1,d2,d3 of LCD.